# Alfresco remote connectivity (for repository metadata querying) alternatives/APIs

Tags: web-services, rest, alfresco, dms

I am new to Alfresco, and trying to investigate what options does it offer for querying information over a repository. Documentation is a bit sparse and there are some different updates. I have 5.0 version as a reference both enterprise and community.

So far, I reach the conclusion that those are the current alternatives:

- CMIS, which supesedes the old Web Services API, and which provides bindings for both WS SOAP and AtomPub, which is community-free
- RESTful API, which I infer is an enterprise-only option
- Old Web Services API (WSDL-SOAP) which is now deprecated
- There is also that Cloud thing which seems to be a different product with some APIs

Am I missing anything ?

I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on the current options and it's cost. Thanks!

Comment: For core metadata and querying, CMIS should do you just fine. What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 1):

For implementing web services in alfresco **web script** is the best way.

For creating web script below link of alfresco is use full.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts

For hello world kind of webscript you need to create below files and put it inside extension(located at tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension) folder of alfresco.

- helloworld.get.desc.xml

> ```
> <webscript>
>   <shortname>Hello World</shortname>
>   <description>Greet a user</description>
>   <url>/helloworld?to={name?}</url>
>   <url>/hello/world?to={name?}</url>
>   <format default="json">extension</format>
>   <authentication>user</authentication>
> </webscript>
> ```

- helloworld.get.js

> model.name=person.properties.userName

- helloworld.get.json.ftl

> ${name}

After deploying above files.Hit below URL in browser and click on refresh webscript button which is located at bottom.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index

Now when you fire url which is written in xml file you will see the output.The tag **<format default="json">extension</format>** specifies the json format.But it will not create output in json format you need to design it in ftl file.There will be only username in json file.

In our case url for webscript is

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/helloworld

you can use documentation link for more details which is specified above.

Comment: Do you need to implement a server-side script even for browsing basic data such as metadata from assets and things like that?

Comment: can you please explain a little more.I am not able to get you in case of browsing metadata.

Comment: Like documents name, number, creation time, and so on among others. Metadata about the respository, for monitoring, not the data itself

Comment: yes for retrieving that in json format or something like that you will need to implement this.